# history.push not re-rendering component (pushing to the same location but with updated data)

Tags: react-router-dom

**Handle Submit of a Form**

```js
axios.post(api.product.create, formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        props.history.push('/sell/allproducts');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message || err);
      });
  };
```

Here I am making a post to an API, it creates the post. The `history.push('/sell/allproducts')` redirects me to the below component that runs the useEffect below on mount

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(api.product.list);
        setProducts(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Here I make another `GET` request to retrieve the new post. But the `history.push` is not re-rendering this component and instead I need to press manual refresh to render.

What might be the problem here?

As far as I can see

- Either the component is rendering even before it retrieves the updated information.
- Or `history.push` is redirecting us to the `url` but not re-rendering the component.

***Note:*** I am pushing to the same `url` and only the state is changing.